# variable change in nested func not recognized in other func with variable passed as arg

Tags: python

I have the following simplified version of my code:

```
import time


def inner(condition, callback):
    while condition:
        print('test')
        time.sleep(1)
        callback()


def outer():
    condition = True

    def callback():
        nonlocal condition
        condition = False

    inner(condition, callback)


outer()
```

Currently, the above code continues to print, even though i change the condition variable to false in the callback function. I want the condition to change to False, and the while loop to exit.

How come the variable change is not detected in the inner func?

Comment: The current value of `condition` is copied into the `condition` variable in `inner`. It's not the same variable as the one in `outer`.

Comment: I thought python passed arguments by reference?

Comment: No, Python does not pass arguments by reference.

Comment: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/3890632)

Comment: Obviously. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: The problem is the `condition` variable value is of type boolean which are immutable. You _can_ effectively pass references to objects which are mutable like a `list`s and `dict`s. For example use `condition = [True]` and you can change the value of its first element via `condition[0] = False` or test its current value with `while condition[0]:` in the `inner()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `condition` in `inner()` is a local variable, `callback()` changes the `condition` defined in the 1st line of `outer()`, but it cannot change the local variable of `inner()`. So, the condition in `inner` will always be `True`. This can be verified by the following code

```
def inner(condition, callback):
    # while condition:
    #     print('test')
    #     time.sleep(1)
    #     callback()
    print('condition in inner before callback(): {}'.format(condition))
    callback()
    print('condition in inner after callback(): {}'.format(condition))




def outer():
    condition = True

    def callback():
        nonlocal condition
        condition = False

    inner(condition, callback)
    print('condition in outer after callback() called in inner: {}'.format(condition))


outer()
```

One work around is changing the `condition` to a list: `[True]`. List is mutable object in python, which means changing it's element will not change it's adress in memory, the `condition` in `inner()` keeps updating with the `condition` in `outer()` :

```
def inner(condition, callback):
    while condition[0]:
        print('test')
        time.sleep(1)
        callback()


def outer():
    condition = [True]

    def callback():
        nonlocal condition
        condition[0] = False

    inner(condition, callback)

outer()
```